# What does the skull icon over an attacking Husk mean?

Tags: fortnite-save-the-world

While defending my fort, I've seen a skull icon appear over an attacking Husk, but haven't been able to figure out what it means. It's happened a few times now, but I was finally able to get a screenshot in time last night.

[image: full image]

[image: zoomed in on skull]

What does this skull mean? If it means anything, I've only ever seen one of these icons at a time and it's always been while defending forts, though I don't believe it's necessarily always been on Husks that were actively attacking a structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although [this Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/FORTnITE/comments/6p5loi/what_does_the_red_skull_on_the_map_mean/) seems to be discussing a different kind of skull, someone also pointed out that the skull above enemies simply means that they have been marked:

> I think your talking about a marked enemy. If you click the mouse wheel on pc you "mark" and enemy with a skull over it's head; it has no purpose other than to draw attention from your allies to that enemy.

[This Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/FORTnITE/comments/6ruc3u/psa_you_can_mark_enemies_for_other_players_to_see/) with a title of "PSA- You can "mark" enemies for other players to see, it will add a skull icon and is easily noticeable by everyone." also seems to confirm (they did it on Xbox One):

> I'm a notorious panic knifer and my friend and I just found this out today by accident. On XboxOne you just click down on the right stick. It's pretty helpful for getting rid of the stronger enemies like smashers.

Comment: Weird, I'll check this when I get home. If it really was me doing it on accident, that'd explain why it seemed to happen randomly...

Comment: @Vemonus also, if it's similar to marking enemies in other games, other party members can mark the enemy and you would see it. This might explain why you aren't realizing what is happening if you are playing with people.

Comment: Hmm that'd make sense, I actually thought it was when Ray said "Hey Fort's under attack" and was basically showing you who.

Comment: @TimmyJim yes, my bad, forgot to accept